# Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia propriatery driver install

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-prime

I require some help and guidance in installing Nvidia drivers on my system with dual Intel/Nvidia graphics processors.

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04, and I am aware that the OS is in its late beta stage, however I perform daily updates. The OS is running fine and smooth, so I can not say that I have experienced any problems.

Following the installation method from below I successfully installed the Nvidia driver without any errors. However upon restarting the system I was presented with a black screen.

Following a solution, I blacklisted the Nouveau Driver and performed another restart whereupon I was presented with the logging screen, but in a 4:3 aspect ratio format. I was unable to continue the login to the Unity desktop because the system froze and rendered the mouse and keyboard inoperable.

Following another solution, I then restarted the system in console mode where I proceeded to check the `nvidia-xorg` file. I noticed the settings looked odd as `Section "Device"` and `Screen` were missing. I tried recreating the file as per instructions using `nvidia-xconfig`, but I received an error:

```
Unable to load X Server Display Configuration page.
```

At that point I gave up and reinstalled Ubuntu. I repeated this process once more, but with no success. I am currently running Ubuntu without the Nvidia drivers and I disabled the card using the method

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends bumblebee.
```

However I would like to get the Nvidia graphics card working.

```
sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```

Hardware:

- Dell Inspiron 15R N5110 laptop
- Intel i5
- Card 1: Intel HD Graphics 3000
- Nvidia GeForce GT525M ("NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 525M]")

Software:

- X.Org: 1.15.0 drivers: Intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0 Hz
- GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.0

Comment: Don't install `nvidia-prime` if you want to use `bumblebee` on 14.04.

Comment: Before installing nvidia-prime, you need to purge! (not just remove) the bumblebee packages.

Answer (score 5):

There seems some issue with optimus dual video systems. You need to open your terminal and enter the commands below:

First remove current Nvidia installation.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install Kernel header if didn't already

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Then install bumblebee using below commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

For more up-to-date nvidia drivers, you need to add another PPA. As of 12.04, this is still necessary for Nvidia GT 6xxM cards. It may be optional for the GT 4xxM and GT 5xxM series on 12.04. When in doubt, just install it. The command is:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

`sudo apt-get update`

Install Bumblebee using the proprietary nvidia driver:

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`

Reboot or re-login

If you have 32-bit applications like Wine, and run 11.10 Oneiric or later, you will need extra libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386
```

Allow yourself to use Bumblebee by adding yourself to the 'bumblebee' group. (replace $USER by your username)

```
sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER
```

Reboot or re-login to apply the group changes If you'd like to run a program on the nvidia card now, use the optirun program:

`optirun firefox &`

Also please look into this thread:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2075423

Comment: Oh i see No Go for my model. I'm sending the Laptop back to Dell in a nice rapped up box, saying I'm using Linux. :) Thank you, its put my mind at rest. I know you took your time writing this Guide but i had a look at he BB wiki site, it didn't mention 14.04 so i assumed you cant install BB, but just to disable the card.

Comment: @Tasos Are you sure not having ability to turn off for now is reason to return it - often things like this will get sorted next version or too. Also, you might consider the preinstalled setups such as this one: http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/xps-13-linux/pd

Comment: I was joking, i cant afford to do that now so i just disabled the car for now. Next time i buy a Laptop it will be full Linux Certified.

Answer (score 1):

I have grown to like `nvidia-prime` better. It runs the whole PC off one card and lets you switch which card to use:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia* bumblebee*
```

Then do

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

You also need `nvidia-319` or higher to use the Nvidia card.

Comment: Are you 100% percent sure it will work with my specs? apparently from checking the link from the answer above there's some details to say its a no go with my specs. Let me know, but make sure and doesn't mess up any thing. I've tried 2 ice already re installing and i have some heavy setup. Thanks

Comment: And switch it for use on everything. Warning windows 7 nvidia updates and proposed ppas aren't a good combination...