# Installing NVIDIA 720M driver in Ubuntu 12.04 with VERIFICATION

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

**

### QUESTION

**

My laptop model is ASUS F550CC with NVIDIA 720M (not optimus) graphics card.

I'm confused with what method should I really use to install NVIDIA 720M in my Ubuntu. Should it be via PPA, Additional Drivers or NVIDIA's website?

What I did was to install the two NVIDIA drivers that appeared in the Additional Drivers upon fresh Ubuntu installation. 
With the image file attached, it can be seen that Ubuntu cannot detect my graphics card.

[image]

I also installed mesa-utils to run glxinfo but I got error messages as depicted in the image file attached below.

[image]

When I run `lspci | grep NVIDIA`, it showed my driver. I'm really confused. One says it cannot be detected, another said it can. What should I believe in? Also how do I really test if NVIDIA is correctly installed (e.g. running some sort of test program)? Also did I installed it correctly?

Here is the detail on how I installed my Ubuntu upto NVIDIA:

> 1. Installed Ubuntu 12.04 x64 without installing updates upon fresh installation. (For faster Installation)
> 2. Installed one of the proprietary drivers and restart.
> 3. Installed the other one and restart.
> 4. Installed mesa-utils.

### Final Update:

[image]

### Troubleshooting process: check the comments also

Running sudo nvidia-settings shows the NVIDIA GUI

[image]

I also run sudo nvidia-xconfig and sudo reboot

Now I got this ugly video resolution. I also run glxinfo again but got the same error message but the details does not display unknown anymore but none at all.

[image]

Here is the /etc/X11/xorg.conf after I executed sudo reboot..

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 331.20  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-05)  Wed Oct 30 18:20:53 PDT 2013

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Running dmesg | grep NVIDIA gives
[image]

Nvidia-settings configuration window
[image]

Comment: what about when you do --- sudo nvidia-settings --- do you get the GUI

Comment: Did you run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`?

Comment: @Tasos Edited the post. Yes I get the GUI. I also attached the image file for it.

Comment: @Danatela Not yet. Should I?

Comment: Yes. It should activate the installed driver.

Comment: What do you get when you click (nvidia-settings configuration) in the GUI???? do you see any Details

Comment: @Danatela I just run it now and it said:

WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'

How do I know if the driver is activated? Also should I reboot again?

Comment: @Tasos Yes I do.

Comment: The xorg.conf file is the Settings file for your Nvidia Card. Before you Reboot Display the file by doing --- cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf --- and post the results to check all is ok

Comment: In any case, Get Familiar with -- nvidia-settings --- as they provide  all the settings for your card if you need to change anything including letting you know if you need an Xorg file or not

Comment: @Tasos I also posted the /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Comment: Now run `dmesg | grep NVIDIA`. Show us the output.

Comment: Ok so your resolution is crap, is it widescreen or square? in anycase run -- sudo nvidia-settings -- again and go to --- xserver display configuration --- and change the resolution to a maximum. You should see an option to Save to X configuration file. Click the option to save the resolution change

Comment: @Danatela: It says:
nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module

Comment: And that's all?

Comment: @Tasos it's square.

Comment: It also printed the date. I'll attach it.

Comment: @Tasos, I can't find an option where you can change the resolution. I also attached the image above

Comment: I think it may be time to Upgade the Nvidia Drivers ---  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates   ---
sudo apt-get update  ---
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  ----  Source http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-The-Latest-Nvidia-Driver-on-Ubuntu-12-04-295542.shtml

Comment: @Tasos Should I uninstall/deactivate the drivers first via Additional Drivers? Or should I start afresh Ubuntu again? :-)

Comment: According to the Doc --- http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-The-Latest-Nvidia-Driver-on-Ubuntu-12-04-295542.shtml  --- "The above commands are useful if you already have the Nvidia driver installed and just want to upgrade it" -- but check it for yourself and make sure its something you want to do. Are you planning to stay with 12.04 for sometime. 14.04 is just around the corner with new Kernel and all the Current System Stuff.

Comment: @Tasos I'm actually requiring the NVIDIA computational power for my thesis in robotics. ROS fuerte is not supported 13.04 and the program code is only supported in ROS fuerte. So I think I got to stick with the old version

Comment: Ok, that make sense, it just maybe though that your Assus Laptop has a problem with Nvidia drivers like my Dell laptop which basic boils down to NVIDIA not including the Cards Headers. I Had the same issue with a square 4/3 screen after installing the drivers and i found out NVIDIA does not include these Headers for my Laptop which they are needed to Compile the Drivers. Ive been looking on the Net to find Out about you Laptop Model, so far nothing but i did find this --- http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Asus/ --- and i cant see your model.

Comment: I think in my country, this laptop has a different name because when Windows detects my laptop model number as X550CC

Comment: I raised the same question recently for 14.04 --  http://askubuntu.com/questions/438601/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-propriatery-driver-install  --- if you cant install the Proprietery NVIDIA driver you may need to go the Bumblebee way. I tell you you something NVIDIA and Linux are a pain to be honest and yes Windows has Full support.

Comment: Oh but i guess you don't have a Dual Graphics Card so you don't need Bumblebee.

Comment: @Tasos But Bumblebee is for Optimus right? My NVIDIA is not Optimus

Comment: @Tasos I already updated the drivers. How do I know if it installed correctly now?

Comment: nvidia-settings ---- will show you the driver version you have --- are you still getting a square 4/3 screen???

Comment: dpkg -l | grep nvidia   --- i think will show you the driver version info too --- current version is  334.21

Comment: Solved! After the upgrade, what I did was search for the proprietary driver and installed it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You post the answer. I think you deserved the credit. So this is how I installed it:

--Install the proprietary drivers---sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates --- sudo apt-get update --- sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --- install the updated proprietary drivers again

I'll post the updated snapshots

Comment: So all ok now??

Comment: I think so. Check my post above.. Search for the text "Final Update".. Details displayed my NVIDIA 720M graphics card :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

Installing NVIDIA 720M card (Non-optimus)

```
1. Install proprietary drivers with restarting after each driver's installation.
2. run the following:
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
3. Install again proprietary driver and restart.
4. Press start and click Details. You will see the graphics card installed.
(We do not need to run sudo nvidia-xconfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run:

```bsh
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo modprobe nvidia
sudo restart lightdm
```

This will activate the installed driver.

Actually, `xorg.conf` is anachronism. Newest X drivers do not need it. But NVIDIA wants it to be written to work properly. Example `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```bsh
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 304.108  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-06)  Wed Jul 31 20:47:43 PDT 2013

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I've updated my post. The resolution is now ugly.

Comment: Now run `sudo modprobe nvidia`.

Comment: I ran it. Nothing happened. Should I reboot?

Comment: just restart lightdm

Comment: I just did too but the resolution is still the same. I also posted the xorg.conf above.