# switching between nVidia GeForce 640M and Intel integrated graphics

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

Hello I'm new to Ubuntu and all in Linux. I have a computer with 8 GB of RAM and a processor Intel core i7 3770S and video card nVidia GeForce 640M and and Intel integrated graphics. In my system information is displayed only integrated graphics Intel. How do I switch to the nVidia GeForce 640M (in the BIOS do not have this function)? Sorry for the grammatical errors, I do not know much English.

Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Enter BIOS when you startup your PC go to the advanced settings or wherever you can find this option **Primary Display Device** and change it from integrated graphics to PCI or AGP or whatever is in there. It looks like your machine is a laptop. Did you install the nvidia graphics card after buying the laptop or was it present from the start. Does Windows detect the nvidia graphics card?

Comment: Yes Windows detect it. And it isn't laptop, it is ASUS All in one PC. And for information my PC has UEFI BIOS. I couldn't install nVida graphics card because it is mono-block.

Comment: See if you Intel card is present in the [following list](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=13815), and go to [this link](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) to download and install Intel(R) Graphics Installer 1.0.4 for Linux. There is a direct link on that page specifically aimed to Ubuntu 13.10 (either 32bit or 64bit). It should be enough for you to be able to run Ubuntu better and faster.

Comment: There is a solution that might work for you, it's a bash script which switches between nvidia and intel video cards. Here's the link: https://github.com/bauca/graphics-switcher

Comment: I have an i7 3630QM with GT650M and tried nVidia drivers many times and simply gave up with all the headaches. So I simply use the iGPU with Intel HD3000 graphics without a problem. Same issue with my i7 6700HQ with GTX 970M although nVidia Graphics drivers were running successfully for a few weeks before breaking. Then I switched over to iGPU with Intel HD 530 Graphics without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use following link to install the Nvidia Prime

[Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia propriatery driver install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438601/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-propriatery-driver-install)

Then execute the following command on your terminal:

To switch to the Intel onboard graphics : `sudo prime-select intel`

To switch to the Nvidia graphics : `sudo prime-select nvidia`

If you want to know which graphics is in use execute the following command:

`sudo prime-select query`