# Ubuntu: Switch from Nvidia to Intel graphics?

Tags: intel, gpu

By default Ubuntu has selected the nouveau drivers as i have an nvidia gpu. But I need to run my system on the Intel GPU instead, with Intel drivers etc. How can I do this?

Comment: this one? http://askubuntu.com/questions/449530/switching-between-nvidia-geforce-640m-and-intel-integrated-graphics?rq=1

Comment: install [Prime Indicator](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html)

Comment: i just tried prime-indicator. it still switches me to nvidia graphics

Comment: doing lspci | grep VGA yeilds only my Nvidia card. How can I install my intel drivers

Comment: @raaj after you switch from prime indicator you have to logout and login back

Comment: I did so. Nothing happens, it continues to remain with the nvidia driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you will have to install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and Optimus.
After that you can switch between the graphics from NVIDIA X Server Settings PRIME Profiles.
Assuming you have a NVIDIA GEFORCE 400 series adapter or newer execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

**Update addressing your response to having problems with 352 drivers**

Use another method - first uninstall the formerly installed NVIDIA drivers.
Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the NVIDIA drivers 358 from the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA.
Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: he wants to use intel drivers. And he does not wants nvidia drives installed but want to switch to intel drivers

Comment: I did exactly as above. same issue, attempting switching using prime-select doesn't work, still stuck on nvidia. Also, my nvidia control panel does not have PRIME Profiles

Comment: @edwardtorvalds : Then the only way to do this is to deactivate the NVIDIA card in BIOS ... in case this is possible ... otherwise you have to install the proprietary drivers. :)

Comment: No i cannot do this. Could it be a driver issue? Perhaps if i downgrade from 352 to something lower prime profiles may work

http://superuser.com/questions/998403/is-it-possible-to-enable-both-onbard-and-pci-e-graphic-card-in-ubuntu

Comment: which other answer

Comment: Should i downgrade to 331?

Comment: Do I do the "nouveau.modeset=0" step first or uninstall first

Comment: unfortunately after purging and rebooting, I get a black screen.

Comment: @raaj : Boot the PC - add the parameter - boot - on install screen enter the commands to uninstall. After a reboot do the same ... and install the new drivers. Just follow exactly the instructions ... in case it does not work with   "nouveau.modeset=0", set the parameter "nomodeset" (without quotes) instead - then boot. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox there is no need to remove nvidia drivers for this purpose! did you see what happened? black screen!!! there are two safe ways to deal with this problem switch to intel by prime indicator or nvidia settings and disable nvidia from bios!

Comment: I just installed your drivers, and tried prime-select. Still doesnt switch

Comment: @edwardtorvalds : Please believe me - this is the most clean, proper and proven to work way to handle drivers installation (given that all steps are executed exactly as described). The fact that PRIME profiles is not available in NVIDIA settings shows that something was not configured properly. This is the reason why everything has to be completely removed before installing new NVIDIA drivers and software. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox how can I just believe you? I see many of your answers give users black screen

Comment: @edwardtorvalds : That's not true - most of all my answers worked ! The black screen issues derives from the open source nouveau drivers incompatibility with many new NVIDIA graphics adapters ... and by the way ... you can see in the comment from raaj above, that he has got the drivers installed meanwhile. :)

Comment: @raaj : Do you have the possibility to select switchable mode or NVIDIA (activating the card) in BIOS ? :)

Comment: I figured it out. I just to need to plug my monitor to the motherboard and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia settings is available in software center.
Install it if not already installed.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-settings
```

Now open it by running this in terminal

```
nvidia-settings
```

From there you will be able to select which GPU you want to use (Nvidia/Intel).

Go to PRIME Profiles -> Select the GPU you would like to use -> Choose Intel (Power Saving Mode)