# Ubuntu 18.04 Nvidia GPU not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

In my nvidia-settings, the PRIME profile shows that NVIDIA graphics card is being used, but in the system setting it's still showing that Intel UHD is being used. Running graphics card in glxgears command also shows that Intel is being used and not the Nvidia one.
nvidia-smi gives an error that it cannot communicate with the device. I have purged and re-installed it completely several times now. I am gone through all most all links I can find about Nvidia and tried everything, nothing seems to work. Help! 
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the mate-optimus tool (https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/mate-optimus), I am using this with gnome session and using it has gotten rid of these problems for me. You don't have to install it from git as it should just be in the normal repos

NOTE: Ubuntu runs a patched version of GDM to make this function properly, it is not (to my knowledge) being carried by upstream Gnome project

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are ***not*** logging in using *Wayland*. At the login screen, click on the little gear icon to select Xorg, for example.

Look also at the last answer (with two upvotes) in: [How to enable NVIDIA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147177/how-to-enable-nvidia)

Comment: Did a combination of your solution along with disabling the Secure Boot and it worked.  Thanks!