# Cannot switch GPUs Lenovo x1 Extreme

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, lenovo, nvidia-prime

I installed 19.10 on a new Lenovo x1 Extreme.

I am unable to use an external display with either usb-c or hdmi. Only one display shows up in Display Settings. There is no movement in dmesg when connecting second display.

Proprietary drivers are installed (nvidia-driver-435).

My problem is that I cannot switch between NVIDIA gpu and Intel gpu. I am able to make different choices in the "NVIDIA X Server Settings" app. But, even after reboot these changes are not reflected in Settings -> Details which always says "Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)".

```
$ sudo lshw -c display

  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:cd000000-cdffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ce080000-ce0fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:153 memory:6040000000-6040ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Ensure that you are ***not*** using *Wayland*. See also this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147177/how-to-enable-nvidia

Comment: It was Secure Boot. I had previously disabled this, then had to reinstall Ubuntu because the wifi on this laptop is not supported until kernel 5.1 (originally I was trying to install 18.04). Forgot to disable it again. Thanks Pilot6.