# Monster Abra A5 Dual Graphics doesn't work

Tags: display, hybrid-graphics, 21.04

So, I just installed Ubuntu and find out my second display is not working. My graphics are Intel HD and NVIDIA 1050 and I'm using 1050. I'm using HDMI port on-board and I think that's probably caused by it. Port may be getting output from Intel HD and I'm using 1050. I have latest 460 drivers. How can I solve it?

```
lshw -C display output:
    *-display UNCLAIMED
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q]
           vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           version: a1
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
      *-display
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 2
           bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
           version: 00
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
           configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
           resources: irq:129 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the outputs of `nvidia-smi` and  `sudo lshw -C display`. I have the same computer (from Monster Notebook), and I was able to connect my computer to a TV set before with no problem (I do not use dual monitors normally). Did you try pressing the function key combination FN+F3 several times?

Comment: fn+f3 didn't work, nvidia-smi gave drivers not found but I have them installed?
added lshw -C display output too.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Sorry for mentioning you but I have classes a couple hours later.

Comment: Can you try by ensuring that you are not logging using Wayland? See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147177/how-to-enable-nvidia for details.