# ubuntu 14.04 :: Grub loader is not visible

Tags: 14.04

The grub loader in my ubuntu 14.04 is not visible .There is a blank screen at the time of starting and automatically directing to ubuntu login page.

Comment: Are you asking how to get to the Grub loader menu?

Comment: yes. i cannot see the grub loader

Comment: Try holding the left shift key down while you boot.

Comment: i did many times. but it is not working. but i can see a black  screen is covering the violet screen. we know the default grub loader have the violet background. so this black screen is like veil for this grub loader. i'm very bad at english language. sorry. hope u got my problem.

Comment: If you do boot into Ubuntu after some time, the method in Sherlock's answer below should work

Answer (score 0):

Install grub customizer from the command line by opening a terminal window and typing:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`

Launch grub customizer by typing:

`grub-customizer`

On the GUI that shows up:

- Click the 'General settings' tab
- Under 'visibility' toggle the 'show menu' toggle box

[Image Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19905635/StackExchange/showmenu.png)

To then apply your changes:

- Click 'Save' on the left-hand side of the toolbar up the top of the GUI
- Go 'File' -> 'Install to MBR'

Comment: where is the visibility toggle? it is not working

Comment: There's no 'visibility toggle'. Under 'visibility' (bold black text) there is a toggle that says 'show menu'.

Comment: [Image of this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19905635/StackExchange/showmenu.png)

Comment: i have [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/502898/ubuntu-14-04-start-to-black-screen-nvidia-optimus) problem

Comment: That thread has been deleted. [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/438601/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-propriatery-driver-install) thread appears to have a potential solution to your problem.